# How to calculate the max row value for each column through Vaex

Tags: python, vaex

I have an application that uses a Pandas dataframe to calculate each min/max row value for each column. For example:

```
col_a  col_b  col_c
2      8      7
10     4      3
6      5      1
```

calling df.max() produces

```
col_a    10
col_b    8
col_c    7
```

Just as a reference the I'm trying to conver the following code:

```
bin_stats = {'min': df.min(),
             'max': df.max(),
             'binwidth': (df.max()-df.min()+10**-6)/bincount}    
 
# Transform data into bin positions for fast binning
data = ((df - in_stats['min'])/bin_stats['binwidth']).apply(np.floor)
```

I'm converting my functionality to Vaex and I need to print out the max row value for every column in my dataframe like above.I have tried df.max(column_names) but I get the error:
`ValueError: Could not find a class (AggMax_object), seems object is not supported`. How do I get an array of max values?

Answer (score 0):

In vaex you can do `df.max()`. You need to pass an expression or a list of expressions for which you want to get the maximum value.

Consider this example:

```py
import vaex

df = vaex.example()
columns = df.get_column_names(dtype='numeric')
df.max(columns)

# returns array([ 3.2000000e+01,  1.3049751e+02,  6.0022778e+01,  5.4506802e+01,
                  6.3641956e+02,  5.7964453e+02,  5.3974872e+02,  3.5941863e+04,
                  3.7393040e+03,  1.7840929e+03, -3.0200911e-01], dtype=float32)
```

Note that vaex has a `df.minmax()` method that can get you the min and max values in a single pass over the data (i.e. faster if you data is larger).

```
float_columns = df.get_column_names(dtype='float')
df.minmax(float_columns)
```

Having said all of this, vaex excels at binning stuff, so it might be worth looking into how to achieve what you want in a "vaex-native" way, instead of straight up translating pandas code into vaex. It should work, but you might not get optimal performance.